# locking and unlocking in a table

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

HELP!!!!
As I am learning rails I am developing this application and I am caught in a few areas.

In my jobs/index.html.erb file All of the jobs are listed for the users regardless if they are admin or employees. The main difference is that if the job is locked, the employee cannot view the details of the job, and if the job is unlocked the details are fully accessible.

My problem is that whenever the image is clicked, the job gets deleted. I am aiming for the image to be clicked ( when logged in as an admin of course) and the lock image changes to the unlocked one and vice versa.

my code in my jobs/index.html.erb file looks like this :

```
 <% if current_user.admin? %>
          <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_job_path(job) %></td>
          <td><%= link_to 'Delete', job, method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %></td>
          <td><%= link_to(image_tag(job.locked ? 'unlock.png' : 'lock.png', size: "18x18"), job, method: :delete) %></td>
      <% end %>
```

currently when the image is clocked the job gets deleted. How can I keep the job and simply change the status from locked to unlocked? I believe I do have to create a method in my controller.

Comment: Why do you have `method: :delete` in your image tag?

Comment: If I remove the method: :delete I am still facing issues.

Comment: @Bala do you have any other suggestions

Answer (score 1):

@Bala's suggestion seems like it's on the right track to me. Removing `method: :delete` won't help you change the locked/unlocked status of your jobs, but you'll at least stop deleting your jobs. Check out this page for more info on the architecture of a `link_to` tag:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to

By including `method: :delete` in that part of your `link_to` tag, you're passing it as a part of the (optional) HTML options hash. The link "name" is the locked/unlocked image, your URL will be populated by Rails (you've pointed it to the Job object), and the method your application will exert on the Job object that link is pointing to is `delete`. If you've left Rails to its typical routing conventions, this means that you're most likely running the `JobsController#destroy` method.

You'll want to add a route and method to your controller that allows you to toggle the status of your job from locked to unlocked. Something like this:

In your routes.rb file:

```
  match 'jobs/:id/toggle_lock' => 'jobs#toggle_lock', :as => 'toggle'
```

In your JobsController:

```
  def toggle_lock
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    @job.locked ? @job.locked = false : @job.locked = true
    @job.save!
    redirect_to jobs_path  ## <= or whatever
  end
```

And finally, in your view:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag(job.locked ? 'unlock.png' : 'lock.png', size: "18x18"), toggle_path(job)) %>
```

Feel free to adjust the logic however you like!